# How to list all root collections and get all products?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this project in Firestore:

```
root
 \_ bags
     \_ id
         \_ name: "Bag1"
     \_ id
         \_ name: "Bag2"
 \_ shoes
     \_ id
         \_ name: "Shoe1"
     \_ id
         \_ name: "Shoe2"
```

And I want to get the names of all collections (bags, shoes, t-shirts etc) and display in a list. On item click, I want to get all specific products. For example, when someone clicks on bags, then I display all the bags. When someone clicks on shoes, I display all the shoes. I know how to display in a list but I don't know how get the collection names in Kotlin/Android/Java? Please help. I tried:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        // bags, shoes, t-shirts etc
    }
});
```

But I have [error](https://i.ibb.co/1XjTtT3/error.jpg).

Comment: You cannot call `get()` on the `db` object, you need a collection first. Is a `bag` object the same as the `shoe` object? I see only one property.

Comment: I have collections, bags, shoes etc are collections. Ok then how to get bags, shoes etc? bag object and shoe object are the same. @Alex mamo

Comment: No, no, you need to call `get()`, on `CollectionReference` object not on a `FirebaseFirestore` object as you do right now. If both are the same, why not to add all products in a single collection?

Comment: I need collections as (bags, shoes, t-shirts etc) not a single collection @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already said in a comment, there is no way you can call `get()` on a `FirebaseFirestore` object, because there is no such method in that class. However, [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) which extends [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html) class contains that method.

According  to your comment:

> bag object and shoe object are the same.

The simplest solution I can think of is to create a single collection named products and add all products in there. This is how your schema should look like:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- products (collection)
         |
         --- productId (document)
         |     |
         |     --- name: "Bag1"
         |     |
         |     --- type: "bag"
         |
         --- productId (document)
               |
               --- name: "Shoe1"
               |
               --- type: "shoe"
```

If you want to get all the products, simply use the following reference and add attach the listener:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("products");
productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Now **you can call `get()`** on this `productsRef` object.

If you need for example only bags, then you should use the following query:

```
Query query = productsRef.whereEqualTo("type", "bag");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

All you need to do is to add just a new property in each product document. That's it.

**Edit:**

To list the types of products, simply create a document with a property of type array and add all types of products.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- data (collection)
        |
        --- types (document)
             |
             --- productTypes: ["bags", "shoes", "t-shirts"]
```

Get the values of this array and add them to a list. Now, when someone clicks on a type, create the query like this:

```
String selectedType = type.substring(0, s.length() - 1)
Query query = productsRef.whereEqualTo("type", selectedType);
```

I have used `type.substring(0, s.length() - 1)`, to cut the `s` from the end o the word.

**Edit2:**

**Honestly, I see no reason why you shouldn't use the above solution** but check below another approach.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- root (collection)
        |
        --- bags (document)
        |    |
        |    --- products (collection)
        |          |
        |          --- bagIdOne
        |                |
        |                --- name: "Bag1"
        |
        --- shoes (document)
             |
             --- products (collection)
                   |
                   --- shoeIdOne
                         |
                         --- name: "Shoe1"
```

In this case, you **cannot** use a simple Query, you need to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
db.collectionGroup("products")
    .whereEqualTo("type", selectedType)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

And to display the product types, please use the following code:

```
productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your logat will be:

```
bags
shoes
t-shirts
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how to get bags, shoes, t-shirts etc?

Comment: I'm sorry but what is not correct? "it's not correct" doesn't help me, help you.

Comment: In my project I need collections.